# TCompressionStream initialize with data

Tags: delphi, zlib

The SPDY protocol specifies to initialize the compression of name/value data with a predefined block of data:

http://mbelshe.github.com/SPDY-Specification/draft-mbelshe-spdy-00.xml#rfc.section.2.6.9.1

(The way zlib compression works is that it will use less bits for strings of characters that 'appear' to reoccur more, so if you pre-load compression with the usual suspects, chances are you'll end up with less bits after compression more of the time. But now for my real question:)

Is this possible with Delphi's TCompressionStream from the ZLib unit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [deflateSetDictionary](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced).  It's available in Delphi XE2's **ZLib.pas**, but the compression stream classes don't expose the `TZStreamRec` field to call it on.  Class helpers can access private fields of the associated class, so you can work around that limitation by adding one to `TCustomZStream` (adding it to `TZCompressionStream` won't work).

```
type
  TCustomZStreamHelper = class helper for TCustomZStream
    function SetDictionary(dictionary: PByte; dictLength: Cardinal): Integer;
  end;

function TCustomZStreamHelper.SetDictionary(dictionary: PByte;
  dictLength: Cardinal): Integer;
begin
  if Self is TZCompressionStream then
    Result := deflateSetDictionary(Self.FZStream, dictionary, dictLength)
  else if Self is TZDecompressionStream then
    Result := inflateSetDictionary(Self.FZStream, dictionary, dictLength)
  else raise Exception.Create('Invalid class type');
end;
```

Just call SetDictionary with the SPDY string immediately after creating the compression stream.

Answer (score 4):

The needed functionality is in ZLib but isn't exposed by Delphi.

Delphi XE2's [documentation for it's ZLib](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ZLib.deflateSetDictionary) has the needed function `deflateSetDictionary` listed as for internal use only. The description for the function in the [ZLib manual advanced functions section](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced) makes it clear it has the functionality you desire.